# Serilog not logging to SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server, logging, serilog, asp.net-core-3.1

In my .NET Core 3.1 project, I have installed Serilog and tried to follow all of the implementing details but  for some reason it is not logging into a SQL Server table.

Here is the code - Web API program:

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            var iWebHost = CreateHostBuilder(args).Build();
            var path = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
            var environmentName = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT") ?? "Production";
            var configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .SetBasePath(path)
                .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
                .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{environmentName}.json", optional: true)
            .Build();

            var logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
                .Enrich.FromLogContext()
                .ReadFrom.Configuration(configuration)
                .CreateLogger();

            Log.Logger = logger;
            iWebHost.Run();
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            Log.Fatal(exception, "Error starting");
        }
        finally
        {
            Log.CloseAndFlush();
        }
    }

    public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
            {
                webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
            })
            .UseSerilog();
}
```

appsetting.json and appsettings.development.json

```
{
"Serilog": {
    "Using": [ "Serilog.Sinks.MSSqlServer" ],
    "MinimumLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Override": {
        "System": "Warning",
        "Microsoft": "Warning"
      },
      "WriteTo": [
        {
          "Name": "MSSqlServer",
          "Args": {
            "connectionString": "Server=localhost; Initial Catalog=GP; User ID=lc; Password=lc",
            "tableName": "Log"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Here is my main controller

```
public class MainController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly ILogger<MainController> _logger;

    public MainController(ILogger<MainController> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }
}
```

And here is the controller that I want to write logs from:

```
public async Task<ResponseBase> GetAsync(RequestBase request)
{
    _logger.LogInformation("in controller");
    // other code
    // return;
}
```

Here is my log entity

```
public class Log
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }
    public string MessageTemplate { get; set; }
    public string Level { get; set; }
    public DateTimeOffset TimeStamp { get; set; }
    public string Exception { get; set; }
    public string Properties { get; set; }
    public string LogEvent { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: You don't have any other sinks so any problems with the database sink won't be logged anywhere. Configure your logger in code first to ensure everything is OK, eg the data source is correct, the server is running, the database exists, the log table is created etc

Comment: @Panagiotis Kanavos I have checked all that. logger is configured and injected, server is running,  database exists and log table also exists

Comment: Your code is calling `UseSerilog` *before* creating the logger itself. By default `UseSerilog()` uses the static logger *or* creates a new one. The way it's called now, there's no static logger to use

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Could you elaborate more please? how can I fix the issue now? what options do I have?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos sorry but you rnaswer below didn't work

Comment: What happened? Did you try using *code* to configure Serilog? You may be reading the wrong file, or have a type. I'm using Serilog to log to SQL Server, configuring it in code,  so I know it works.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217967/discussion-between-artavazd-and-panagiotis-kanavos).

Answer (score 2):

Your code calls `UseSerilog()` before Serilog's configuration. This means the application ends up with a default, unconfigured logger. You can avoid this by configuring Serilog using [inline initialization](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-aspnetcore#inline-initialization) with the `UseSerilog` overload that provides access to the HostingContext. From the linked docs:

```
.UseSerilog((hostingContext, services, loggerConfiguration) => loggerConfiguration
    .ReadFrom.Configuration(hostingContext.Configuration)
    .Enrich.FromLogContext()
    .WriteTo.Console())
```

This reads Serilog's settings from configuration *and* adds a Console logger, ensuring you'll get log messages even if the configuration is incorrect.

There's no reason to create the configuration separately. `CreateDefaultBuilder()` sets the current directory as the root and adds the `appsettings` files. To extend this, use `ConfigureHostConfiguration` or `ConfigureAppConfiguration` after `CreateDefaultBuilder()`.

`CreateHostBuilder` should change to :

```
public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
    Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
        {
            webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
        })
        .UseSerilog((hostingContext, services, loggerConfiguration) => loggerConfiguration
            .ReadFrom.Configuration(hostingContext.Configuration)
            .Enrich.FromLogContext()
            .WriteTo.Console());
```

and `Main` to just :

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    CreateHostBuilder(args).Run();
}
```

If you want to use the logger *before* building the host, you should create it before calling `UseSerilog()` :

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
            .Enrich.FromLogContext()
            .ReadFrom.Configuration(configuration)
            .WriteTo.Console()
            .CreateLogger();

    try
    {
        CreateHostBuilder(args).Run();
    }
    catch (Exception exception)
    {
        Log.Fatal(exception, "Error starting");
    }
    finally
    {
        Log.CloseAndFlush();
    }
}

public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
    Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
        {
            webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
        })
        .UseSerilog()
```